# Inequality for integral of Dirichlet kernel

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following from an exercise in 'A Radical Approach to Real Analysis' by David Bressoud:

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n > 0$ and $0 \leq \zeta < a \leq \pi/2$ then
\begin{equation*}
\left| \int_{\zeta}^{a} \frac{\sin[(2n + 1)u]}{\sin u} \mathop{du} \right| \leq \int_{0}^{\pi/(2n + 1)} \frac{\sin[(2n + 1)u]}{\sin u} \mathop{du}.
\end{equation*}

If $0 \leq \zeta < a \leq \pi/(2n + 1)$ then the inequality should hold because the integrand is $\geq 0$ on $(0, \pi/(2n + 1)]$.

I can see qualitatively that it should also hold for $0 \leq \zeta \leq \pi/(2n + 1) < a \leq \pi/2$ because the integrand is always initially negative after $\pi/(2n + 1)$ and is oscillating towards 0. However I am having trouble showing this quantitatively.

I'm less certain about $\pi/(2n + 1) \leq \zeta < a \leq \pi/2$.

Would anyone have advice on how I might approach this?

Comment: You want something like the alternating series test: split the integral into intervals on which the integrand is positive and on which it is negative (as you have started to do already), and then show that the integral over each interval is less than that over the previous one.

Comment: @Chappers: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble showing that the integral over each interval is less than the previous one. I can put an upper bound on each one, but that isn't enough. Any hints on doing this?

Comment: @Chappers: I think I might see how to proceed. We have that $\sin[(2n + 1)u]$ repeats itself on each alternating interval and $1/\sin(u)$ is monotonically decreasing on $(0, \pi/2]$. Therefore the integrand on each alternating interval is less than the integrand on the previous alternating interval?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea (although I hope you mean "$1/\sin{u}$ is monotonically increasing on $(0,\pi/2]$").

Comment: I meant as $u \to \pi/2$.